# Get archive from another page and unzip it in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails app i need to update my pricelist from another service, but trouble is in that:
how can i get archive from another site to my storage, unzip it, and do what i need (import from unziped rar archive csv file). Could anybody give idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very broad question, but just to point you in the right direction:

- Use the [`Net::HTTP` library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) to retrieve the file to your system.
- Use either a Ruby library capable of handling RAR files (I don't know what they are), or a command line tool like `unrar` (using `system`) to extract the archive.
- Use the built-in [`CSV` library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) to handle the CSV.

With all the error-handling, scheduling, and other tasks that come with such a process, this is not really something that can be fully explained in a single answer.

Comment: i need more firs part, getting to my disk